# Reduced bundles and global sections of associated bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles

I am following **Kobayashi and Nomizu's book** **Foundations of differential geometry volume 1**  **(page no $57$)** ***Proposition 5.6.***

> The structure group of a principal bundle $P(M,G)$ is reducible to a closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ if and only if the associated bundle $E=(P\times G/H)/G\rightarrow M$ has a global section. (Here we use the notation $Q(M,H)$ for the reduced bundle.)

One direction  I was able to understand. Given that $G$ is reducible to $H$, I was able to produce a global section for $E\rightarrow M$.

For the other direction, I was able to understand everything except that I could not prove $Q$ is an immersed submanifold.

If the following result is true, then I am done.

> ***Is the inverse image of an immersed submanifold an immersed submanifold under smooth submersion?***

I know the above result is true for embedded submanifold (Using transversality) but I am not sure about the result for immersed submanifold.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - use that an immersion is locally an embedding to reduce to the case of an embedded submanifold.

Added:

Let $U$ be the immersed submanifold with preimage $V$. Cover $U$ by embedded submanifolds $U_i$. The preimages $V_i$ are embedded and cover $V$, so $V$ is an immersion.

Comment: Thanks @Ben for the answer!..I think you are talking about local embedding theorem. But to use the result to boil it down to the embedded case  I am needing another result that I am not sure  of.. I need union of embedded submanifolds is an embedded submanifold... Is that true? Or we have to approach in a different way? I am Sorry if my remark is stupid.

Comment: @ADITTYACHAUDHURI The union of embedded manifolds is only an immersed manifold. But that good enough right?

Comment: @ADITTYACHAUDHURI By the way I added another line of explanation.

Comment: @ Ben Thanks! Actually I never came across about the result that the union of embedded submanifiolds is an immersed submanifold. Since there are examples where union of submanifolds is not a submanifold I never thought in that direction.Can you please refer me a literature (or give a brief outline ) for the proof of the fact that union of embedded submanifolds is an immersed submanifold? I could not see directly that local embedding theorem is equivalent to "This Result".  Sorry in advance if my remark is stupid!

Comment: @ADITTYACHAUDHURI Here by "union of embedded submanifolds" I just mean it is a union of open subsets which are embedded. That is, given $M \to N$ and $U_i$ covering $M$ such that $U_i \to N$ are embeddings, I am saying "$M$ is a union of embedded manifolds". But this is just the condition of locally being an embedding.

Comment: Thanks@Ben for the comment!